# PKIX path building failed in development enviroment but not in localhost

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I am developing a Java application that needs to connect to an LDAPs server. The fact is that the LDAps is using a self signed certificate and that I have to import it in the keytool of my jdk in order to avoid getting a PKIX path building error.

After importing it, I have seen that the login is done correctly with LDAPs in my local machine. Once application has been proved in localhost correctly, I have deployed it in a development enviroment that has its own tomcat and jdk installed.

I have copied the cacerts of my local machine to the development enviroment and when I try to login the application via LDAPs, I am getting de PKIX error.

In order to prove that the cacerts has been correctly copied to the development enviroment, I have overwrite the one of my local machine with the one of the development enviroment and still works.

I have also created a .jar that tryies to authenticate via ldaps in the development enviroment and it works. So, can anyone tell me why is my application returning PKIX error?

Comment: Maybe you are coping to a wrong JDK.

Comment: I have checked the jdk that is being used and it is the right one.

Comment: The cacert can be set using `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` JVM parameter. please set this parameter and check is it working

Comment: I have tried what you said and I have solved the problem. What I don´t understand is why it isn´t working if I haven´t specified any cacerts. Shouldn´t it take the default one?

Comment: If the setting JVM parameter works then what you think the default cacerts is not the default one.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was going crazy with it!